# Passing variables from PHP to Javascript with wp_localize_script function

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I´m trying to get my PHP variables into a JS file, in my wordpress plugin. Following the cake recipe, a code the below snippet.

*** PHP ***

```
$someone = 'whatever';

function admin_script_style( $hook ) {
  global $post_type;
  wp_register_script( 'my_scripts', plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) .'/js/' . 'scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
  wp_enqueue_script( 'my_scripts' );
  wp_localize_script( 'my_scripts', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'my_var' => 'foo' ) );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_script_style' );
```

This works fine, but, if I change "my_var" for a PHP variable, like

```
wp_localize_script( 'prd_scripts_edicoes', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'my_var' => $someone ) );
```

This fails, my javascrip returns "my_var = null".

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `$someone` is not within the scope of your function.

You can import it into the scope, by declaring it as global and then accessing it:

```
global $someone;
$someone = 'whatever';

function admin_script_style($hook) {
    global $someone;
    // $someone is now accessible
    ...
}
```

Note that, you don't *have* to declare a variable as global when you're setting it, if you're already in the global scope. I prefer to always declare a variable as global if I plan on accessing it within a child scope, for the sake of being explicit.

Alternatively, instead of using a named function for your hook, you could pass a closure to `add_action` and declare `$someone` as a used variable:

```
$someone = 'whatever';
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', function($hook) use($someone) { 
    // $someone is now accessible
    ...
});
```